# Android wshttpbinding support

Tags: android, wcf, soap, wshttpbinding

I want to connect to a Soap 1.2 web service but as I understand it, android doesnt support wshttpbindings. So I tried the ksoap2 lib which should be able to send a correct soap action.

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.headerOut = SoapUtils.buildHeader(SSL_URL, SOAP_ACTION);
```

I even tried to write the header but Im just not sure what Tags are really needed for a wshttpbinding. 
Does anyone know how to use the wshttpbinding under android? I already took a look at the other questions but nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Better try with basicHttpBinding. The wsHttpBinding uses some advanced message security (depending on your settings) which is not supported in Android. Transport security (ssl) will be easier.

Comment: I know that basicHttpBinding would be easier but I didnt write the wsdl service so I don t realy have a choice. But it cant be impossible to simulate a wshttpsbinding in android. PS: The service has a self signed cert and credentials which makes it even more complicated.

Comment: what is the exact wshttpbinding configuraiton the server uses?

Comment: Thats the 100k question. I have no clue cause my boss made the service and I dont have access. But if there is no way to call the service he has to change the service setting or I write a second dotNet Rest service which accesses the wsdl service. I dont see another way. Do you?

Comment: do you have the WSDL of the service? it has the ws-policy tags that can say what is the server binding

Comment: Yes I have the wsdl but it doesnt include a ws-policy tag. I have wsp:Policy tags which include sp:TransportBindings. Do mean these tags?

Comment: yes, please publish it here. TransportBinding may imply that SSL is used and not Ws-Security

Comment: Sorry for the delay but here is the policy: [Policy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0c13p06i5c3vacv/Policy.txt). I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this is interoperable with android. This looks like security mode of "TransportWithMessageCredential", clientCredential="Username" and establishSecurityContext="true". This is not a simple configuration. you would need a specialized java library to call this. I know axix2 and wsit work on desktop (even so it is hard to use them) but not sure they are avialable to android. I suggest to change this binding and if not possible use the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I have connected to the wsdl service. The clue is that the service needs a primary request which returns a SecurityContextToken. This token is needed for additional request. The first soap envelope looks like this:

[image: SecurityTokenRequest]

If I send this soap envelope to the service it returns the SecurityToken which can be used for other requests. 
But Im not sure which tags are really neccessary for the SecurityTokenRequest because in this request there are a few uids and tag values which change each time and I dont know how they are contructed. For example the MessageId, the UserToken id, the BinarySecret Tag,...

Does someone know which tags are cructial and which are not?

I used a HttpsUrlConnection and an OutputStream:

```
        URL url = new URL(SSL_URL);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        urlConnection.connect();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        if (out != null)
        {
           out.write(getReqData());
           out.flush();
           out.close();
        }
        int res = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        String message = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        String msg = convertStreamToString(in);
```